# PreLoad and Load event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET, just a question on page life cycle:

The MSDN doc says: **"Raised after the page loads view state for itself and all controls, and after it processes postback data that is included with the Request instance"**, which means, I can also put the programming logic here

```
protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label1.Text = "Hello World; the time is now " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

so why we always do like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label1.Text = "Hello World; the time is now " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

?

Answer (score 5):

The `Page_Load` event handler will properly handle creation of all page controls. Per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140)):

> The Page object calls the OnLoad method on the Page object, and then
>   recursively does the same for each child control until the page and
>   all controls are loaded. The Load event of individual controls occurs
>   after the Load event of the page.
>
> Use the OnLoad event method to set properties in controls and to
>   establish database connections.

...which means, based on your example, the `Label1.Text` may get reset by that control's `OnLoad` event (depending on the individual control's implementation; I do not know if this is true for `Label` control, but it would be in compliance with the documentation if that did happen).

Comment: so why not just get rid of Load event so we can use PreLoad?

Comment: @amjad they are used for different purposes; `PreLoad` is primarily there for *3rd party controls* to handle their internal state before the `Load` event, but after `Init` event, so that *Viewstate* is loaded, but user code in `Load` hasn't ran yet.